# Create forms with powermail in TYPO 11.5.21

Tags: forms, typo3, powermail

yes, it's me with a further, maybe stupid question. I'm very new in TYPO3, I just started working with it. I know some programming languages but no typoscript. Therefore I'm working with the bootstrap package first.

I made some forms in TYPO3 and so far everything was fine but there wasn't any possibility to customize the email (to sender). Therefore I first installed "Form: Mailtexts via plugin" but afterwards the form was not working anymore and I deleted it and everything was fine again.

After some research I have found powermail for creating forms with loads of cool functions.

So, I read four different tutorials about making forms in powermail and it's not working at all.

As far as I can evaluate the problem, I would guess that the last step is the problem, because now I just see a "Hello World" site when loading the page???

I have no idea what I did wrong.

Many thanks in advance for your hints :-)

cheers,
roland

I did internet research and experiments

Answer (score 0):

If you just see "Hello World", than I guess there is a TypoScript record on your root page which loads this dummy content.
using https://www.sitepackagebuilder.com/ you should get a custom site setup in quite a short time

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I don't know were to start. If you see a "hello world" output in TYPO3 in the frontent, your problem is not related to powermail but to your basic configuration. First of all you have to use some lines of typoscript to get a valid output of your content elements.
I would add some pages and some textmedia content elements on it with a bit of a lorem ipsum dummy text.
After that you should open the main TypoScript template and write something like:

```
page = PAGE
page.10 < styles.content.get
```

Don't forget to add the TypoScript from fluid_styled_content to get an output. And if you get your first real output of your content elements, you can add a form with a page and some fields and add a content element of type powermail plugin.

There are some learning videos how to start with TYPO3. Maybe this helps you for your first steps.

I wish you success